# Ulr Routing в Codegnither?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Вроде бы простая тема, но разобраться не могу.
Есть такая структура:

**Класс = Pages**

**Функция = view**

**Параметр функции = $page**

Url получается такой: **http://mydomain/pages/view/portfolio**

Открывается страница Портфолио.

Делаю Роутинг в файле routes.php вот так:

**$route['portfolio'] = "pages/view"**;

Вызываю вот так - **http://mydomain/portfolio**. Открывает нормально, но выдает ошибку, что я не передал параметр в функцию view. Почему? Что за прикол?

Answer (score 1):

**$route[':any'] = "pages/view/:any";**

Если кому будет интересно как это!